# regex with 2 non consecutive spaces

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that allows strings with no more than 2 non consecutive spaces inside.

```
WORD is ok
WORD WORD is ok
WORD WORD WORD is ok
WORD WORD WORD WORD is not ok
```

i don't care about consecutive spaces by now.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how your example corresponds with the rest of your question.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: the string is allowed to be composed by no more than 3 words!!! One word is good, two words is good, four words is not good! I don't know if exist a regex to do so!! just asking.. :)

Comment: So the regular expression should match 4 or more consecutive words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a negative look-ahead to prevent a match if a string contains more than two non-consecutive spaces

```
^(?!\S*\s+\S+\s+\S+\s)
```

Alternatively, a valid string will match

```
^\S*\s*\S*\s*\S*$
```

Comment: thank you.. it works.. is there a way to force the words to be composed only by letters and numbers??

Comment: @Janinho67 you can use \w+ instead of \S+. \w is equal to `[A-Za-z0-9_]` so beside letters and digits it will also accept underscore. If you don't want to accept underscore use `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use back references for this:

```
/(\b.+\b)\1\1\1/
```

For example,

```
/(\b.+\b)\1\1\1/.test('HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO'); // true
```

Whereas,

```
/(\b.+\b)\1\1\1/.test('HELLO HELLO HELLO'); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
^([^ ]+\s+){0,2}[^ ]*$
```

It assumes that you don't have space at start of your line.